# How to wait for a callback to have run for older browsers that don't support promises and/or async await?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a piece of code that will run only on IE 11 or older browsers. These browsers do not have the `Promise` object and so don't support the `async`/`await` API either.

I have a method like so:

```
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThing();

  // I'd like to run the following lines
  // only if the successCallback passed
  // to the $.ajax method inside doTheThing
  // has been called
}

function doTheThing() {
  $.ajax(..., successCallback(data) {
  });
}
```

**Busy Wait: Blocking the main thread**

If I use a busy wait while loop, that will block the main thread and never let pending messages in the message queue execute. As a result, my `successCallback` will never get a chance to execute while the busy wait loop runs, like in the following code:

```
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThing();

  // This will stall the thread indefinitely and 
  // freeze the application
  while(!window.done);

  ...

}

function doTheThing() {
  $.ajax(..., successCallback(data) {
    window.done = true;
  });
}
```

**Writing the rest of the continuation inside the callback**

I could write the rest of the code that I'd like to run *after* the `successCallback` runs inside the body of the `successCallback`, but that's just going to make my code really ugly. I don't want to do that.

```
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThingAndThenEverythingElseAlso();
}

function doTheThingAndThenEverythingElseAlso() {
  $.ajax(..., successCallback(data) {
    ...

    // the continuation here
    // yada

  });
}
```

**Writing the rest of the continuation inside setTimeout**

Or I could write the continuation, i.e. the rest of the code that I want to run after the `successCallback` inside a `setTimeout` call like so:

```
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThing();

  setTimeout(function() {
   // the continuation here
  }, 3000);
}

function doTheThing() {
  // set a timeout on the ajax call
  $.ajax({ url: ..., timeout: 3000 }, successCallback(data) {
    window.done = true;
  });
}
```

This, too, makes my code ugly and difficult for a reader to know the express intention of the author.

So, how do I block the current thread while allowing it to process messages from the queue?

Comment: how about  https://babeljs.io/? It converts modern javascript to browser compatible code. Try  it!

Comment: @garryman God, I was aware of that. I was going to mention it but I forgot. I *hate* transpilers.

Comment: the Babel compiler will compile async functions to using Promises, so you're sod out of luck there unless you also use a Promise polyfill.

Comment: @DanPantry you're right, and there's the bluebird polyfill for that, but I hate polyfills, too. I hate anything non-standard.

Comment: So you're going to use callbacks, which are a non-standard solution to this problem, instead of using a polyfill for a standard? wild :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callback into `doTheThing` and call it when you've run the rest of your `successCallback` code:

```
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThing(function() {
    //do stuff after TheThing
  });

  ...

}

function doTheThing(callback) {
  $.ajax(..., successCallback(data) {
    //other stuff
    callback();
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's basically running the continuation from inside the success callback, but I'll take this route for now. Seems like the only sensible way.

Comment: This is essentially what Promises and async/await are putting syntax sugar around.

Comment: Correct. I have promises all over the rest of my files. I am writing a small file for my IE users. 6 more minutes before I can mark this answer as the right one.Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using a Promise shim/polyfill instead of rewriting your code to use callbacks for IE users?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a function to `doTheThing`, which is how we used to do it before Promises.

```
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThing((error, data) => {
    ...
  });
}

function doTheThing(cb) {
  $.ajax(..., (data) => {
    ...
    cb(null, data)
  });
}
```

If you use the `(error, data)` argument convention (ie a Node-style callback) you can even use helper libraries like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) to help organize this code.

You could alternatively use a [Promise shim](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise), which  would not require a compiler.

I would personally recommend using the Promise shim since it means you don't have to write your code differently for older browsers. The downside of the shim means that you would, however, have to have the user download more code before your stuff starts working, so TTFR would be a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another function and call it into the success of your ajax request.

```js
$(document).ready() {
  doTheThing(anotherCode); 
}

function doTheThing(callBack) {
  $.ajax(..., successCallback(data) {
    callBack();
  });
}

function anotherCode() {
  // I'd like to run the following lines
  // only if the successCallback passed
  // to the $.ajax method inside doTheThing
  // has been called
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? He's saying exactly the same thing that James Thorpe is saying.

Comment: I downvoted because the answer was much different before its edit - it was edited quickly, though, so I retracted the downvote. Previously, it suggested calling `anotherCode()` from within `doTheThing()`.